Leak behind tiled shower wall
I have a leak behind my shower wall. It seems to only leak if the tile wall gets sprayed or splashed. I had a plumber tell me it was because of old faucets and fittings, but a handyman told me it was a leak in the "skin" of the shower wall and to paint the tiles and grout.
Is this a plumber issue or one for a contractor?
Edited for detail:
the leak seems to be coming from behind the faucets but only when sprayed. The faucets do leak on the inside of the shower but does not appear to leak behind the wall unless directly sprayed or from splashing off of a body.
The plumber wants to tear up the wall to  fix the faucets but not the wall after how ever my handyman says it's just a contractor issue and not the faucets.

replace and seal the grout

Grout is porous and is not meant to be a waterproof barrier. The waterproof layer lies under the tile. If, as you and the handyman suspect, the problem is with the tiled wall and not the fixture(s), the correct repair requires you to "tear up the wall" anyway. If/when you do that, you should consider replacing the "old faucets and fittings".

Thank you for the info, this is basically what I was thinking. I just didn't want to do one and end up having to do the other as well.

Get a plastic drop cloth and tape it around the shower walls and use as you normally would. Check for leaks. If the leaks stop, your wall is the problem. Examine the grout lines and caulk lines and redo any areas that have cracks or missing areas. If the leaks continue, then it is probably the valves or where the shower head fits into the wall.

Thanks for the info

Painting the tiles will do nothing except make work.
Replacing the grout might fix it if the wall is leaking.  The wall gets wet when using the shower.
So the plumber might be right also.
A small hole for an inspection camera in the untile section or the wall behind the shower will tell if the pipe for the shower is leaking.

Luckily I have an access panel so I can get a pretty clear view behind. The leak comes from behind where the inside of the wall is cut for the faucets. I've applied caulking around all the faucets but still there's a leak when water runs down the wall in that area. My guess is I might have to tear it up and redo it but I was hoping I might be wrong. I guess that's a problem with owning a 109 year old house
